# how to get directory of images to access via code

Tags: android, storage, android-drawable, android-sdcard

I want to add images with my app. I see option to add images in `res/drawable` folder. But I have lot of images. How can I access the directory? 
e.g. to access sdcard location I can use

```
File directory = new File(
        android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM);
```

But I have images in drawable folder which will be with app. So how to access directory in android project. So that I can use something like `File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();`
Is there better way to save and access images through app?

Comment: If you need to access images, why wouldn't you just call `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.name_of_drawable)` ? My question is why do you need reference to drawable folder ?

Comment: "How can I access the directory?" -- there is no directory. Resources are files on your development machine. They are not files on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I can suggest you is to store your images into "Asset" folder in your project and you can easily access all the images at once by following these steps:

1. Create a folder named "images" in your asset folder.
2. Copy all your images in that "images" folder.

3.Get your images list like this:

```
String[] images =getAssets().list("images");
ArrayList<String> listImages = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(images));
```

4.Now set the images to your "imageview" like this:

```
InputStream inputstream=mContext.getAssets().open("images/"
                                  +listImages.get(position));
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputstream, null);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access all you images in drawable folder with  :

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.name_of_drawable)
```

and also if you want access or load many images , you can use same names ( with postfix / prefix ) and load theme in a loop easily